# Is it a buzzkill when killing an enemy with specialist hardline?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

So all of you know that a buzzkill is when you kill someone 1 kill of their next killstreak. So would that mean that killing somebody with 0 kills running specialist hardline would make it a buzzkill?

Answer (score 2):

The coding is bugged (perhaps purposely) so that if someone has 0 kills, 'buzzkill' can never take place (even if someone is a specialist and they have hardline).

With that exception, however, 'buzzkill' will apply if someone has hardline, and has 2 or 4 kills.

Comment: doesn't sound like a bug to me, it's probably to avoid people from farming buzzkills for bonus xp

Comment: Agreed. I did mention they may have done so purposely.. Nonetheless there at least is a wording issue with buzzkill.

Answer (score 1):

NO, a kill is counted as a buzzkill only when your victim is one kill away from his next kill streak whatever the situation. So for example if your victim has a killstreak of 'predator' which is a 5-kill reward, but becomes 4-kill reward with hardline, you must kill him when he is at 3 kills to obtain the buzzkill.

Comment: What he is saying is that if you run the specialist streak package, your first "killstreak" (perk reward) is for 2 kills, so 1 kill if you run hardline along with it. So killing someone with 0 kills could be considered killing someone "1 away from his first killstreak".